# Export To excel from 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, data-export

I have Two data frames
Both have Months column in them
I want to export to excel (create excel files) by df1 months

```
dint_month = df1['month'].unique()
outputfile = pd.ExcelWriter(str(value)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for value in dint_month:
        month1 = df1[df1['month']== value]
        month1.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='Course', index=False)
        outputfile.save()
```

This creates the files and exports the data to the files as I want it to do
Now I have a DF2 where I have month column and weekly updates
So I want to add that weekly information in separate worksheets in the same month excel file I exported from DF1

I tried one more for loop but that exports all weeks to all the files. Please if you can suggest, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `sheet_name` for the other dataframe?

Comment: I did, it exports all the weeks in all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataframe `df2` which would have both a reference to your monthly data and to your weekly data. One option would be to proceed as follows:

```
dint_month = df1['month'].unique()
for value in dint_month:
    outputfile = pd.ExcelWriter(str(value) + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    month = df1[df1['month'] == value]
    week_data = df2[df2['month'] == value]
    month.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='course', index=False)
    week_data.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='course_weeks', index=False)
    outputfile.save()
```

---

Note that there are a couple of things going on:

First, the ouput file creation line was moved within the loop as it was dependent on your `value` variable.

```
outputfile = pd.ExcelWriter(str(value) + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Then we filter the week data on a `month` column identical to your first dataframe. (given that its there).

```
week_data = df2[df2['month'] == value]
```

Finally, we output that data to another sheet by changing the sheet name on the same output file.

```
week_data.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='course_weeks', index=False)
```

This set up works in the scenario where `DF2` also has a month column. If that is not the case you would also have to add a month column to your second dataframe or to rename the `month` in `df2[df2['month'] == value]` to your actual column name.